# How to handle files with leading dashes

Tags: linux, shell, file, find

I am searching for files and directories using `find`, the files have leading dashes in the filenames:

```
ls -al

total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 razhal  staff    0 May 22 23:58 -x
drwxr-xr-x   3 razhal  staff   96 May 22 23:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 razhal  staff  384 May 22 17:06 ..


find * -maxdepth 1 -type file
```

The above gives the following error message:

> find: illegal option -- m

I tried to terminate the options using `--`, but still having the same problem:

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -type file --
```

The strange thing is that if the folder contains a file without a leading dash I am getting no error message:

```
ls -al

total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 razhal  staff    0 May 22 23:58 -x
drwxr-xr-x   3 razhal  staff   96 May 22 23:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 razhal  staff  384 May 22 17:06 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 razhal  staff    0 May 23 00:03 x

find * -maxdepth 1 -type file
```

The above returns the `x` and no error message.

My question is how can I find and list both files/directories with and without leading dashes using `find`?

Notice that I really want to use `find` and not some other command such as `xargs` or similar.

Comment: Find is normally given directory names to search through, not filenames like you're doing... Use `.` instead of a wildcard that expands to all files in the current directory?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed since I still can not manage to handle files or directories with leading dashes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` instead of `*`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type file
```

`.` refers to the current folder you are in. You can also use `..` instead of `.` to search from the parent directory.

Another option would be to put `./` in front of `*` like this:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 1 -type file
```

This way it won't interpret the files whose names start with a dash as options.

Comment: Using just a '.' as proposed in the comment also seems to work, but then I have an other issue, since the located filename contains the `./` part as well and I would like to only get the filename so I can do things like this `find ./* -type file -exec mv {} temp{} \; `

Comment: would this work for you? `find . <flags> -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I{} mv {} temp{}`

Comment: Like I said I would like to use only find and no other commands such as xargs or similar.